# How to bypass Close Dev Tools and Reload Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

```
url = 'https://ww3.gogoanime2.org/watch/isekai-meikyuu-de-harem-wo-uncensored/1'

path = 'C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe'
headers =  {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer' : 'https:google.com',
    'DNT' : '1'
}
options = Options()
options.binary_location = path
options.add_argument('proxy-server=106.122.8.54:3128')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:/Users/caaka/AppData/Local/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/User Data/Default')
driver2 = uc.Chrome(options = options)
driver2.request_interceptor = headers
driver2.get(url)
```

[image]

I'm trying to write a script that will extract the.m3u8 file after the webpage has been loaded. However, it detects devtools in this case and video doesn't get loaded. I'd like to avoid it. Is there another way to get there network tab info without having to load a webpage?

Comment: yo this seems an interesting project. can i join ?

Comment: You are welcome to join. But I'm stuck with this current issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked in network requests in chrome devtools I found request on photo 1 and photo 2 [find request looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2TMB.png) and
[copy link consisting of t_u t_d and t_t arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJvTR.png)

{*https%3A%2F%2Fgogoanime.vc%2Fsword-art-online-alicization-dub-episode-4&t_d=Sword%20Art%20Online%3A%20Alicization%20(Dub)%20Episode%204%20%20at%20gogoanime&t_t=Sword%20Art%20Online%3A%20Alicization%20(Dub)%20Episode%204%20%20at%20gogoanime*} - link in my example

And just open link in browser that worked for me